# Make Windows 7's taskbar look (not behave) similar to Vista's

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I recently switched from XP to 7.  I tried Vista in a VM, and I do like the Vista taskbar look.  But having googled around, all I find is "How to make XP/Vista look like 7" or "Make 7 behave like Vista".  All *I* want is "Make 7 look (*not* behave) like Vista".

I've found one site with info on getting the Vista look on 7.  But that, for some unfathomable reason, requires actually patching a system lib.  I'd prefer not to have to do so.

I mean, all I *really* want is to get that glossy taskbar.  Me just likes! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe add a "glossy look" texture to the Windows 7 taskbar using the [**Texturized Taskbar**](http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Texturized-Taskbar-141576124) tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-get-back-vista-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joseph's answer, you can also [Add the Quick Launch Bar to the Taskbar in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/), then unpin all items from the taskbar by using the right-click.

Answer (score -1):

I Suggest Either Using Classic Shell (A Program In Mind For Changing The Look Of The Start Menu And Taskbar,And Many Other Features). Or You Can use This Tutorial To Apply A Theme That Will Give The Taskbar The Texture And Vistas Minimize And Maxixmize Buttons
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7fOwrlGzH0